# Shopify python api intermittent connection errror

Tags: python, shopify

I keep getting the following error while trying to use the Python Shopify api:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/will/workspace/modernprints-django/shop/export.py", line 226, in <module>
    prints()
  File "/home/will/workspace/modernprints-django/shop/export.py", line 122, in prints
    copy_metafields(fields, old_print, new_print)
  File "/home/will/workspace/modernprints-django/shop/export.py", line 35, in copy_metafields
    'value_type': 'string',
  File "/home/will/virtualenv/modernprints-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shopify/mixins.py", line 22, in add_metafield
    metafield.save()
  File "/home/will/virtualenv/modernprints-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 824, in save
    data=self.encode())
  File "/home/will/virtualenv/modernprints-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 364, in post
    return self._open('POST', path, headers=headers, data=data)
  File "/home/will/virtualenv/modernprints-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shopify/base.py", line 23, in _open
    self.response = super(ShopifyConnection, self)._open(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/will/virtualenv/modernprints-django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py", line 290, in _open
    raise Error(err, url)
pyactiveresource.connection.Error: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

It will work for a minute or so, then stop. Using shopifyAPI 2.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

If it was working before perhaps you reached your API call limit? Try seeing if this is true by trying to get the response status code when you make a call.

I'm only suggesting this because you said it worked for you before. However, I'm curious to know if you received any data back from Shopify from you API call?

Remember, to make an API call using the python Shopify API is:

```
session = shopify.Session(params['shop'], token)
shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)
```

Not that this only works after you setup the session with the Shopify App keys as well.

Comment: It's not the api limit, you get a specific error about that if it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something wrong with my internet connection, which strangely wasn't noticeable while doing other things.
Tried using Google's DNS and switched to Ethernet rather than wireless and it started working properly.